# Using SVG icons in Shopify

Tags: svg, shopify

I have over 30 svg icons I want to use in my Shopify theme. For readability sake I do not want to add then directly in the .liquid template but to use include:

```
{% include 'some-icon' %}
```

and some-icon.liquid to have the SVG code

The problem is that all these 30 files will have to reside in my Snippets directory. With all the other files in Snippets it will be a mess.

Is it possible to create an additional directory in Shopify and import them from there:

```
{% include 'MyIcons/some-icon' %}
```

Any other way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: slightly off topic, but if your SVG icons are monochromatic you could use https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom to convert them into a font. I did this 6+ months ago for a project and couldn't be happier.

Comment: monochromatic ??? You can add any color with fill. Font-face means additional request and are not semantic, this is what I am trying to avoid in the first place

Comment: roger. but by monochromatic i meant that the icon is a single uniform color, and didn't include any gradients - because that wouldn't transfer well to a font glyph.

Answer (score 9):

Been looking for a simple and maintainable way of adding SVG icons to Shopify. Here is my best way found. If you know better please let me know.

In Snipets create file 'my-theme-icons' witch will contain:

```
{% if my-theme-icons == 'home' %}
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
... my home icon
</svg>
{% elsif my-theme-icons == 'search' %}
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
... my search icon
</svg>
{% endif %}
```

In your templates just include them as:

```
{% include 'my-theme-icons' with 'home' %}
{% include 'my-theme-icons' with 'search' %}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: really straightforward, easy implementation. thank you very much

Comment: Would be much better to use a case statement

Answer (score 1):

```
{% include 'icon' with 'shopify' %}
```

Call the icon you want, and arrange them in a snippet with a case statement.

```
<!-- snippets/icon.liquid -->
<span class="icon" aria-hidden="true">
  {% case icon %}
  {% when 'shopify' %}
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="shopify" aria-label="Shopify" role="img">
      <title>Shopify</title>
      <desc>Shopify {{ 'icon.icon' | t }}</desc>
      <path d="M13.3 3.1C13.3 3 13.2 3 13.1 3c-0.1 0-1.3-0.1-1.3-0.1S11 2 10.9 1.9c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.3 0 0 0-0.2 0.1-0.5 0.1C9.8 1.2 9.5 0.5 8.3 0.5 8.1 0.1 7.8 0 7.5 0c-2.1 0-3 2.6-3.4 3.9C3.3 4.1 2.8 4.3 2.7 4.3 2.3 4.5 2.2 4.5 2.2 4.9c0 0.3-1.2 9.4-1.2 9.4l9.1 1.7 4.9-1.1C15 14.9 13.3 3.2 13.3 3.1zM8.3 2.6c-0.5 0.2-1 0.3-1.6 0.5 0.3-1.2 0.9-1.8 1.4-2C8.3 2 8.3 2.6 8.3 2.6zM7.4 0.6c0.1 0 0.2 0 0.3 0.1C7.1 1 6.3 1.7 6 3.3 5.6 3.4 5.2 3.6 4.8 3.7 5.1 2.5 6 0.6 7.4 0.6zM7.8 7.5c0 0-0.5-0.3-1.2-0.3 -1 0-1 0.6-1 0.8 0 0.8 2.2 1.1 2.2 3.1 0 1.5-1 2.5-2.3 2.5 -1.6 0-2.4-1-2.4-1l0.4-1.4c0 0 0.8 0.7 1.5 0.7 0.5 0 0.6-0.4 0.6-0.6 0-1.1-1.8-1.1-1.8-2.9 0-1.5 1.1-2.9 3.2-2.9 0.8 0 1.2 0.2 1.2 0.2L7.8 7.5zM8.8 2.4c0-0.1 0-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.2 0.5 0.1 0.8 0.6 1 1.2C9.4 2.3 9.1 2.4 8.8 2.4z" class="fill"/>
    </svg>
  {% when 'menu' %}
    <!-- SVG CODE GOES HERE -->
  {% when 'cart' %}
    <!-- SVG CODE GOES HERE -->
  {% else %}
    <!-- {{ icon | capitalize }} icon not found -->
  {% endcase %}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot make up directories for assets, or snippets, or other theme components. In your local development environment where a mess matters, perhaps you can colour code your files by extension to keep the types more obvious, or turn on some sorting by extension to do same.

Comment: I understood that. What do you think of my solution with {% include 'my-theme-icons' with 'search' %}. Any performance issues? Thanks

Comment: No performance issues with that, although the snippet could end up being pretty messy itself. I'd suggest `{% include 'my-theme-icons', icon: 'icon-home' %}`.

That way your snippet can be vastly simplified by using variable `icon` instead of a bunch of if statements for `my-theme-icons`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a task runner (like Gulp or Grunt) to build an SVG icon sprite (there are several modules that do this). Your src files can be outside of the theme folder, ultimately concatenated and added to a snippet that you include immediately after the opening `<body>` tag. One more `icon.liquid` snippet then references and "uses" them:

```
<svg class="icon icon-{{ icon }}">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-{{ icon }}"></use>
</svg>
```

You would include that snippet like this: `{% include 'icon' with 'logo' %}`